# Is there a javascript library to parse simple queries?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, pattern-matching, string-matching

I want to filter a list of strings according to whether certain words are contained in the string, or are absent from the string, or some combination. I'd like the input to be straightforward, for example:

```
input: "foo AND bar"
output: All strings containing 'foo' and 'bar'

input: "foo OR bar"
output: All strings containing 'foo' or 'bar'

input: "foo AND NOT bar"
output: All strings containing 'foo' but not 'bar'
```

This would be fairly simple to write, but has anybody done this already so I don't have to re-invent the wheel in a less optimal fashion? This will be user-facing and I don't want the user to have to learn how to use regular expressions.

Comment: these statements are going to "compile" into regular expressions? database queries? what is your end goal?

Comment: oh I thought it was clear; let me update my question

Comment: I doubt that anything like this exists in Javascript

Comment: @SimpleCoder: same, figured I'd ask anyway

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any library, but you could use jQuery's :contains selector to write something like that easily.

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: How will that handle boolean queries? I think that's the gist of his question -- translating all the AND and OR operators into appropriate selectors.

Comment: It is, and it won't help with that - but it could give a head start and "not re-invent the wheel".

Comment: I just have a list of strings. I can use `.indexOf`.